# Help choosing slider

Tags: javascript, joomla, content, design

I'm looking for JS implementation of effect similar to:

http://www.citroen.it/home/#/home/   main slider

Joomla! module will be the best solution, however, standalone JS snippet is also an option.
I'm looking for both free and commercial solutions.

Could you please advice something similar?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a jQuery 3d wall carousel type plugin one such plugin is available at http://dyndo.com/rough/?p=110 with a [Demo here](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/jquery3dwall)

Comment: Really nice thing, but it seems to be Webkit-only. If it was cross-browser, I would immediately mark this as a solution. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: This is another carousel with similar effects http://www.elated.com/articles/cover-flow-remade-with-css-and-jquery/

Comment: This one is complaint with all browsers http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/features.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched the [extension directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/slideshow)? Which version of Joomla do you use?

Maybe one of these [JQuery Plugins](http://www.qubesys.com/200-best-image-slider-jquery-plugins/) is sufficient for you?

Comment: Joomla 3.0, but older versions are also on option.